# SimpleJDBCCall Spring not execute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have this method

```
public void importarAdiantamento(ArrayList<LayoutArquivo> arquivos, Usuario usuario) throws Exception {

        try {

            for(LayoutArquivo arquivo : arquivos) {
                DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");    
                SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("DATAVCM", new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(arquivo.getVencimento()).getTime()))
                        .addValue("VALOR", arquivo.getValor())
                        .addValue("MOTIVO", arquivo.getCodMotivo())
                        .addValue("EMPRESA", arquivo.getCodEmpresa())
                        .addValue("NPARCELA", 1)
                        .addValue("TOTALPARCELA", 1)
                        .addValue("DOCUMENTO", arquivo.getDocumento())
                        .addValue("FUNCIONARIO", arquivo.getCodFunc())
                        .addValue("HISTORICO", "VALE IMPORTADO")
                        .addValue("EXPORTAR", 0)
                        .addValue("USUARIO", usuario.getCodigousuario())
                        .addValue("DUPLIC", 0)
                        .addValue("PROTOCOLO", "0");


                SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)                                          
                        .withProcedureName(AdiantamentoQueries.importarAdiantamento())
                        .declareParameters(
                                new SqlParameter("DATAVCM", Types.DATE),
                                new SqlParameter("VALOR", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("MOTIVO", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("EMPRESA", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("NPARCELA", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("TOTALPARCELA", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("DOCUMENTO", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlParameter("FUNCIONARIO", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("HISTORICO", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlParameter("EXPORTAR", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("USUARIO", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlOutParameter("DUPLIC", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlParameter("PROTOCOLO", Types.VARCHAR)
                         );


                System.out.println("executando o documento " + arquivo.getDocumento());
                jdbcCall.execute(in);
                System.out.println("terminou de executar o documento" + arquivo.getDocumento());

            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

When arrive in line `jdbcCall.execute(in);`
The execution hangs like you're waiting and not continue.
No have idea what going on

I printed information in console and only this is printed

```
executando o documento 72527
```

Since I can only commit when all of the `for` records have been successfully completed, I had placed the `@Transactional` annotation but it did not work either

after run this method is java, this is a sessions in my database:

[image]

Comment: Please make the changes suggested below and run the code. Let me know if you get any exception.

Comment: no have anyone exception. I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you saw in database if your transaction is running?
- Do you executed that procedure directly in database instead of run in java?
- Not exists any process running in parallel causing a lock in database?

Hope I helped you.

Comment: 1 - not yet, but i will verify now
2 - yes, it works
3 - not, this database is of test, and only i have connected

Comment: i add printscrenn in question. I belive to be some thing in spring

Comment: lu.koerfer When I tried leave a message the stackoverflow show me the message: You must have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: 1+ because it was a session of sql server management studio giving lock

Comment: Jeterson, try to enable debug log mode, maybe the spring show something.

Comment: Mickael, the StackOverflow show to me "You must have 50 reputation to comment.". Then I just wanted to help Jeterson. Now I have reputation for leave a comment in the post.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno Carletti, realmente era um lock na tabela.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you are running the jdbcCall in for loop, it is better to declare `jdbcCall` object outside the `for loop`. You don't need to create this object in each iteration.

2) When you use `@Transactional`, the method should not handle the exception with `try-catch` block. So, please remove the try-catch block and annotate the method as mentioned below.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```